# How to enable scroll bar for JQuery qTip1.x

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, qtip, qtip2

I am using jQuery qTip1.x,It is showing dialogue box properly but when i zoomIn and zoomOut in browser the dialogue box is overflowing in the window with(only half of the dialogue box it is showing)

The following images shows the problem with zooming.

[No issue when browser is in 100% mode](http://snag.gy/NMTnK.jpg)

[Issue when zoom out 120%](http://snag.gy/MC4Ey.jpg)

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Add css overflow property to your dialog.

```
overflow: scroll;
```